# error using rename function in PHP

Tags: php

I keep getting this error, although the file still gets moved into the correct directory. Anybody know why i'm getting this error?

```
Warning: rename(../Images/uploaded/1162504_56863010.jpg,../Images/uploaded/Portraits/1162504_56863010.jpg) [function.rename]: No error in D:\Data\Websites\wamp\www\StephsSite\PHP\addImage.php  on line 21
```

Comment: Which version of php and which OS do you use? If possible try to update to the latest version. Might be related to http://bugs.php.net/48771

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? There was a bug related to this pre 5.3: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48771&edit=2

Comment: @VolkerK, you beat me to it :-)

Comment: Yea it is 5.3. I'm using wampserver2. I'll have to check and see if there's an update for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [User Contributed Notes](http://de.php.net/rename) to `rename()`, there are issues on Windows systems when the target file already exists.

- try [unlink()](http://www.php.net/unlink) ing the target file first if it exists
- Alternatively, try [**copy()**](http://de.php.net/copy)

Comment: that could be as well when trying to move to different volume https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50676

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is simply to hide the warning:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
rename($old_name, $new_name);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```