# Is there a tool to batch convert UTF-8 filenames back to ISO-8859-1 on windows?

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding, filenames

I downloaded a lot of files within multiple subdirectories from a remote FTP server, the issue is that these files have non latin file names and they downloaded with weird characters like: `Ã«, Ã, Ã¬, Ã¹, Ã` and `ط§ظ„ظ…ط±`

Is there a way to roll back these file names to their original names? maybe with a windows based batch tool?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm doing this just so i can upload the files with the correct names to a new server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
  $filename = Split-Path -Leaf $_
  $new = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($filename))
  if ($_.Name -ne $new) {
    Rename-Item $_ $new
  }
}
```

might work. The whole `Rename-Item` call could maybe be done easier, but I usually run into trouble when not using the full path so I err on the side of caution.

Comment: It says: Method invocation failed because [System.Text.Encoding] doesn't contain a method named 'Default'.

Comment: Oops. Fixed now. Still untested (apart from the actual encoding conversion), though.

Comment: and by the way does this look for files in the directory where the script is located?

Comment: Now it says: Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.

Comment: Hm, try again now. I hate doing filesystem stuff and I frequently notice why ;)

Comment: It works for your first example now, the second one throws an exception.

Comment: It says: Source and destination path must be different :)

Comment: That's a fairly trivial fix, though :P

Comment: I fixed the type by adding ")" and the script ran without errors, but didn't do anything

Comment: How to do this recursive?

Comment: @Sam: You add `-Recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem` call.

Answer (score 0):

With php:

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    rename( $filename, mb_convert_encoding( $filename, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8") );
}
```

Comment: hey, it almost worked, it threw this: `Warning: rename(Ø³ÙƒÙˆØ±Ø©-Ù…Ø¯Ø§Ø².jpg,?????-????.jpg) [function.rename]: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\enc.php on line 3` i counted the question marks and they're the exact number of correct characters that should be there. What do you suggest?

Comment: It displayed that warning but didn't do anything to the actual file.

Comment: @Ryan did it work on other files or gave the same error for all of them? Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440500/error-using-rename-function-in-php It worked flawlessly for me when I tried though :/ (Windows, php 5.4.5)

Comment: @Ryan if you can, update to php 5.4. It seems to be bug in < 5.3? Are you using 5.2?

Comment: Tried it on 5.4.4, doesn't do anything and doesn't throw an error