# Java is failing in the midle of a copy from src to target

Tags: java, maven

Suddenly I am getting this error while building my project.

```
typ[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-cli) on project utk: There are no more files -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-cli) on project utk: There are no more files
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: There are no more files
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: There are no more files
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:300)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: There are no more files
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1868)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:122)
    ... 23 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExceptione here
```

First I got this during 'mvn clean build'. but I am also getting this during 'mvn resources:resources'

The strange think is that I havent really change anything on my code, the only significand change was that I moved from Avast security to Windws Defender Security but that might be irrelevant..

So back to the issue, the project has 3036 files under resources, most of them are .txt and .properties files. During the copy I am getting this error message, not at the same file everytime.

I am wondering if it is a memory issue or cache size, I dont know.

I am using java 1.8 and maven 3.2.3.

Tried maven update, update repository, restart, checkout the code again, adding eclipse and java to Windows Firewall excepsions and many other things I found online. Nothing seams to work..

I tried to delete most of the resources files and tried to build again with 1003 files, still failing.

Adding the pom.xml build section after request:

```
<build>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>com/AAA/microwave/XXX/about.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>com.AAA.microwave.XXX.XXXMain</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>test-jar</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.AAA.microwave.XXX.XXXTestMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-tests.jar ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar MMM-XXX-${project.version}.jar MMM-ubt-${MMMVersion}.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>rxtxparallel</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <type>dll</type>
                        </artifactItem>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>rxtxserial</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <type>dll</type>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${delivery.directory}</outputDirectory>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>XXXAppli</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>XXXAppli</finalName>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/XXX_exe_zip.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: possible to add pom.xml?

Comment: added above @prasannajoshi

Comment: <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    <resources>
    <resource>
</resources>
 <artifactItems>

try adding resource under Configuration like above

Comment: I am getting "Unrecognised tag: 'configuration'" I guess it should be part of a plug in to be able to use the configuration tag

Comment: You setup is simply outdated.. the plugin version is of 2014!! That means not updated for such a long time... Also using Maven 3.2.3 the same time... upgrade.... also this copying with maven-dependency-plugin etc. looks strange... and also using maven-assembly-plugin which not using maven-assembly-plugin instead etc. Resources in `src/main/java`??

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanx for your comment. Your first point is to update to a new verion of maven which I have replied in the below comment. Is there another point or question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that it took me two weeks to solve this thing.

The problem is discribed here in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58825588/does-java-need-to-support-error-no-more-files-when-canonicalizing-paths-on-windo/77401318#77401318) and you may find the solution there too.

I am just adding the solution here too, which is to a registry in windows.

Adding this registry: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters**DirectoryCacheLifetime=0 (DWORD)**

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using Maven 3.2.3, which is quite outdated. Consider upgrading to a more recent version of Maven, as newer versions often come with improvements and bug fixes. Also you can enable Maven debugging to get more detailed information about what's happening. Add the -X or --debug flag to your Maven commands, e.g., mvn clean install -X

Comment: I would like to do that too, and I will probably do it at the upcoming wweeks but I am getting all depedencies from an internal server and I dont have access to add the new maven there. i should wait another team to do it. meanwhile I need to be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

tried the below but still fails. The problem is not consisten either. sometimes after a restart it is working for a while and then it fails again. I believe that it is reaching some limmit because I am tring to copy a lot of files.

1. run this script to all ther resources (-Recurse) using PowerShell:
   [Is there a tool to batch convert UTF-8 filenames back to ISO-8859-1 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098282/is-there-a-tool-to-batch-convert-utf-8-filenames-back-to-iso-8859-1-on-windows)
2. Change the re pom.xml resource section to the below:

   ```
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/java/com/AAA/microwave/XXX/</directory>
           <includes>
               <include>about.properties</include>
           </includes>
       </resource>
   </resources>
   ```